# Convert web scraped string list to formatted CSV

Tags: python, csv, web, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a quick little script to web scrape data from a website and save the results out into a formatted CSV.

So far using BeautifulSoup and have been able to get the data I want from the website, encode it so it can be saved to CSV, but its in a long string with not logical formatting (that I can see) and I'm trying to figure out how to convert it.

Code:
    # import libraries
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# specify the url
quote_page = 'url'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = soup.find('ul', attrs={'id': 'list-store-detail'})

name = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
print name

# open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name.encode('utf-8')])
```

Current Output:

```
Name 
Address 1
Address 2
Country
Name + Address
Phone Number
Street View
Direction







Name 
Address 1
Address 2
Country
Name + Address
Phone Number
Street View
Direction
```

[Desired Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLJW1.png)

As you can see there is massive white space inbetween and from what I can tell it doesn't actually have any \n\r.

I'm assuming I'm going to have to somehow split the string up into lines, for loop through and then format it into the CSV correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct! There's likely a more efficient way to do this, but this requires very few code changes.

**Split the string using**

```
split_name = name.split("\n")
```

**Get rid of blank lines**

```
no_blanks = [ x for x in split_name if len(x) > 0 ]
```

**Write to CSV**

```
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
line = []
for i in range(len(no_blanks)):
    line.append(no_blanks[I].strip())
    if len(line) == 8:
        writer.writerow(line)
        line = []
```

**Output**

`Name,Address 1,Address 2,Country,Name + Address,Phone Number,Street View,Direction
Name,Address 1,Address 2,Country,Name + Address,Phone Number,Street View,Direction`

Comment: Perfect, thank you that worked. Had to mess around finding where to put a line to encode first before writing to CSV, but seems all good.

Comment: Can you share where you put it so I can update the answer?